# how to filter a time field in a list between two times

Tags: django

I have created an app where an interviewer can fill out forms and schedule multiple interviews. this is the model for the schedule:

```
class ScientificSchedule(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

and I wrote this view for it:

```
class ScientificScheduleView(FormView):
    template_name = 'reg/scientific-schedule.html'
    form_class = ScientificScheduleForm

    def post(self, request):
        form = ScientificScheduleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ScientificScheduleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

it works fine. I want to add a statement to the form_valid function that checks if another schedule in that timespan already exists. for example imagine that this particular user has an interview from 8 a.m. to 10 a.m. He is not allowed to schedule another interview between 8 and 10. How do I make it check the user's previous interviews objects and see he is allowed to submit this form or not?
I want something like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if ScientificSchedule.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, province=form.instance.province, date=form.instance.date, 
start_time__in=[a list between two times from other interviews on that specific date]).exists():
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    else:
        form.save()
        return super(ScientificScheduleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

how can I filter it like this?

Comment: You probably want that code to live in the form.clean method and let it raise a ValidationError with a meaningful description. You can use a ModelForm. Also I don't  think it's necessary to override the post method in the View: Django already takes care of that. Same goes for the form_valid, for that matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django validating time slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981109/django-validating-time-slot)